# Google execution API script error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api-js-client

Google Execution API runs fine with "devMode:true" but throws script error when devMode is changed to true.

1. I have deployed my script as API executable.
2. I have given access to anyone.

I am able to get the success response but when I am changing `devMode` to `false` or when I am skipping the line `devMode:false`
the API returns Script Error

```
var request = {
  function: 'postData',
  parameters: [order],
  devMode: true
};

// Make the API request.
var op = gapi.client.request({
  root: 'https://script.googleapis.com',
  path: 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
  method: 'POST',
  body: request
});
```

Comment: Do you mean throws an error when devMode is changed to false?

Comment: What does the error say? Permission Denied or something? –